# is it possible to intercept network packets outside lan?

Tags: network, man-in-the-middle, routing, internet

User A is in a different country than user B and they have different IP ranges and ISPs.

Is it possible for A to intercept B's communication sent to a third party, without using techniques like malware attacks, phishing, etc. I.E without access to B's computer.

Sort of what you see in Hollywood movies.

Comment: It depends on who A or B is and what control they might have of the networks in-between the sender and the 3rd party

Answer (score 1):

> I.e without access to others computer.

I'm assuming that you mean that A cannot access the computer of B and B not of A, but they can access other computers on the internet.

Since information are not exchanged directly between parties but involve multiple hops there are several ways to intercept the data. Just to give you an idea what can be done here are some real-life examples:

- Have some kind of wiretaps at these hops: This includes [backdoors](http://www.wired.com/2015/12/juniper-networks-hidden-backdoors-show-the-risk-of-government-backdoors/) in routers or firewalls, wiretaps at central hops like several state agencies (NSA, GCHQ) have, hacking the router...
- Divert the traffic through hops which are controlled by the attacker: This includes  [BGP spoofing](http://www.bgpmon.net/bgp-routing-incidents-in-2014-malicious-or-not/) but also [changing the DNS settings](https://nakedsecurity.sophos.com/2012/10/01/hacked-routers-brazil-vb2012/) in SoHo routers with CSRF attacks or similar.